# How to group of 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, syntax

I have 2 arrays like this

```
$head = array(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 14, 14, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2); //count =22

$customer = array(1, 7, 9, 13, 14, 1, 9, 13, 1, 13, 14, 1, 9, 14, 2, 8, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3, 8); //count=22
```

And I want to group this 2 arrays by consider at `$customer`,  if `$customer[0]=1` in `$customer[1-21]` and `$head[1-21]` will not have a value `1`, such as in the `$head[1]` have a value `1`, So delete at `$head[1]` and `$customer[1]`. And then consider at `$customer[6]`. The value is `9`. It means in `$head[7-21]` and `$customer[7-21]` will not have a value `9`.

I am trying to write a code for this concept like this. Here is my code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($head); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($customer); $j++) {

        if ($customer[$i] == $head[$j]) {
            unset($head[$j]);
            unset($customer[$j]);
        }
        if ($customer[$i] == $customer[$j]) {
            unset($head[$j]);
            unset($customer[$j]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($head);

print_r($customer);
```

the result is of $head and `$customer` is:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [6] => 14 [7] => 14 [13] => 13 [14] => 3 [15] => 3 [16] => 5 [17] => 8 [18] => 8 [19] => 8 [20] => 2 [21] => 2 ) 

Array ( [0] => 1 [6] => 9 [7] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 2 [15] => 8 [16] => 8 [17] => 2 [18] => 3 [19] => 5 [20] => 3 [21] => 8 )
```

I found that it's wrong. Because the real result should be:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [6] => 14 [7] => 14  [14] => 3 [15] => 3  ) 

Array ( [0] => 1 [6] => 9 [7] => 13  [14] => 2 [15] => 8  )
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: The problem was using unset, which just unset the value but does not rearrange the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is all ok but when you unset a particular index then all other index after when you iterate it again then i index is missing. Just open the error and warning then you will see

> Notice: Undefined offset

I have just replaced your uset to assign it to `''`. So you can understand it

```
<?php

$head = array(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 14, 14, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2); //count =22

$customer = array(1, 7, 9, 13, 14, 1, 9, 13, 1, 13, 14, 1, 9, 14, 2, 8, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3, 8); //count=22


for ($i = 0; $i < count($head); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($customer); $j++) {

        if ($customer[$i] == $head[$j]) {
            $head[$j] = '';
            $customer[$j] = '';
        }
        if ($customer[$i] == $customer[$j]) {
            $head[$j] = '';
            $customer[$j] = '';
        }
    }
}

print_r(array_diff($head, [''])); // remove all the '' entries

print_r(array_diff($customer, [''])); // remove all the '' entries
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `count()` only returns a count of the set elements in the array. So if you unset them it will be reduced and you won't arrive at the end of the array. To fix, calculate the count at the start and store in a variable:

```
$headcount = count($head);
$customercount = count($customer);
for ($i = 0; $i < $headcount; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $customercount; $j++) {

        if ($customer[$i] == $head[$j]) {
            unset($head[$j]);
            unset($customer[$j]);
        }
        if ($customer[$i] == $customer[$j]) {
            unset($head[$j]);
            unset($customer[$j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have never know this issue before. Thank you a lot for your kind assistant. :)